# Arduino Actuated relay

Tags: arduino, switches, relay, servo

I'm developing a device with an Arduino that has to switch off a servomotor that has 3 wires: GND, +12v and pwm signal.
I'm not sure where is the best place to put the relay to switch off the motor.
This is a particular servomotor controlled by a computer, what I need to do is to switch it off using an RF remote.

I don't have a datasheet or detailed informations because it's an OEM part and informations are not public.
My question is, is it correct to stop it functioning by placing the relay on the GND wire? I'm thinking about the GND because if I put it on the PWM or +12v it will be still powered on and maybe it could have some malfunction

What do you think about it?

Comment: Hello Ste, can you give more information about the servo motor and maybe a schematic/image of how you plan to connect the hardware together?

Comment: If it's truly a servo motor, you don't "switch" it on or off.  Please edit your question and explain EXACTLY what you have, how you are hooking it up and what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: If the servo can be controlled by PWM input, relay not necessary. It may have a driver embedded.

Comment: I've update the question a little bit, it's a servo controlled by a computer but I need to to avoid this to be opened and closed when I need it by using a RF remote. The circuit is really simple, relay connected to the Arduino that opens and closes one of the 3 wires  going to the motor to avoid it to work connected to NC and COM output of the relay

Comment: You say in your question that the servo has only GND, 12v, and PWM connections, then you say it has two sources of power. We can't help you if we don't know what you're working with. Please provide a part number or more detailed description of the servo.

Comment: It has only one source of power and the pwm signal. I don't have a datasheet or detailed informations because it's an OEM part and informations are not public. It's a special valve that has 3 wires +12v, PWM signal, and GND. What I need to do is to place a remote controlled switch (using relay and arduino) that stops this valve to operate when I need. My question is, is it correct to stop it functioning by placing the relay on the GND wire? I'm thinking about the GND because if I put it on the PWM or +12v it will be still powered on and maybe it could have some malfunction